# How can I pass ACL inside upload method of gcloud-aio-storage client library?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, acl

I am trying to upload an image to a google cloud storage bucket using gcloud-aio-storage client library. I want the image to be accessible publically. I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find an option to pass predefined_acl or acl in the upload method. I have written the following code :

```
import asyncio
from gcloud.aio.auth import Token
from gcloud.aio.storage import Storage

async def upload_image(bucket_name, image_name, data):
    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"]
    token = Token(service_file="key.json", scopes=SCOPES)
    async with Storage(token=token) as client:
        image = await client.upload(bucket=bucket_name, object_name=image_name, file_data=data)
    await token.close()

    return image["name"]
```

I have also tried the following piece of code as suggested by other resources on the internet but it didn't work:

```
image = await client.upload(bucket=bucket_name, object_name=image_name, file_data=data, acl='publicRead')
```

I am using the following version of gcloud-aio-storage :

```
Name: gcloud-aio-storage
Version: 9.2.0
```